# No match 'operator = ' in std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, map

Всем доброго вечера!

У меня есть вектор такого вида:

```
vector< map <BYTE,ifunct*> > FuncBytes;
```

Пытаюсь с ним работать вот так:

```
FuncBytes[sign] = pair<BYTE,ifunct*>(n, changMethod);
```

и так:

```
FuncBytes.at(sign) = pair<BYTE,ifunct*>(n, changMethod);
```

Но в обоих случаях получаю синтаксическую ошибку:

> ошибка: no match for 'operator=' in 'FuncBytes.std::vector<_Tp,
>   _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = std::map, std::allocator > >, _Alloc = std::allocator, std::allocator > > >](((unsigned int)sign)) =
>   std::pair(((const unsigned char&)((const
>   unsigned char*)(& n))), ((ifunct* const&)((ifunct* const*)(&
>   changMethod))))'

Я так понимаю, ему pair не нравится? Как тогда правильно присвоить словарю значение?

Comment: Тьфу, блин. Все, разобрался ((map <BYTE,ifunct*>)FuncBytes[sign])[n] = changMethod;

Comment: Ничего кастовать не надо, можно записать просто `FuncBytes[sign][n] = changMethod;`

Comment: Хранить сырой указатель не есть гуд. Можете утечку получить. Используйте vector< map <BYTE,unique_ptr<ifunct>> > FuncBytes;